# Как правильно делать "отзывчивую" типографику?

Tags: css

Постигаю премудрости "отзывчивой" верстки и столкнулся с проблемой типографики, а конкретно - размеры шрифтов. Почитал [пару](https://css-tricks.com/viewport-sized-typography/) [статьей](http://www.cmsmagazine.ru/library/items/graphical_design/build-responsive-site-week-designing-responsively-part-2/#) и пролистал [книгу](https://abookapart.com/products/responsive-web-design), после чего засел за макет. Некоторое время подумав, я решил использовать единицы измерения [вьюпорта](http://caniuse.com/#feat=viewport-units). Казалось бы, чего проще: берешь размер текста (32px), делишь на ширину вьюпорта (1920px), получаешь результат 1,666666666666667vw, который и применяешь в таблице стилей. Однако, когда размер вьюпорта составляет 960px, то размер шрифта составит уже 16px (это еще нормально), но при разрешении 760px размер шрифта составляет 12,66667px и соответственно пропорционально уменьшается, становясь нечитаемым на мобильных девайсах. И это при базовом шрифте в 32px. Если текст на макете шириной 1920px составляет 16px, то уже и на ноутах с планшетами будет проблематично ег прочитать. В связи с этим прошу советов у сообщества: как организовать правильную "отзывчивость" типографики?

Comment: Не согласен с идеей. По мне так лучше в адаптивке оставлять шрифты неизменными - ибо это база представления информации. Не хотите уродливо большие шрифты - манипулируйте масштабом страницы ( тегом meta viewport , которым можно также управлять из JS ) - например задайте минимальную ширину, дальше которой страница не сжимается. Иначе происходит двойная работа. ИМХО.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Есть достаточно свежая (от 17 августа 2016) статья с методикой, как раз по плавному изменению типографики - размер шрифта и интерлиньяж в заданном диапазоне: http://blog.typekit.com/2016/08/17/flexible-typography-with-css-locks/

И такой же свежий плагин к PostCSS, реализующий методику: https://github.com/bramstein/postcss-scale

Answer (score 2):

Можно использовать медиа-запросы для разной ширины экрана:

```
@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .my-text{
    font-size: 10px;
  }
}
@media (min-width: 992px) {
  .my-text{
    font-size: 12px;
  }
}
@media (min-width: 1200px) {
.my-text{
    font-size: 14px;
  }
}
```

Comment: при таком подходе изменение размера происходит скачкообразно. Обратите внимание на приведенный пример: он не гипотетический. Если я применю медиа-запросы, то изменение размера шрифта слишком "рваное": 32px, 18px, 16px, 12px...

Comment: Есть очень свежая статья именно по плавному изменению. Я пока не читал ее и не применял, поэтому полный ответ вам сформировать не могу, но ссылкой делюсь: http://blog.typekit.com/2016/08/17/flexible-typography-with-css-locks/

Comment: можно через media сделать "вилку" с минимальным и максимальным размером шрифта, а что в середине - плавно

Comment: @DmitryKozlov, примерчиком поделитесь, если не жалко :)

Comment: LiveAlex  по моему перепад не большой : http://codepen.io/Geyan/pen/gryyrK?editors=110

Comment: @gambala мне помогла ссылка на статью, оформите свой комментарий ответом, я отмечу его как верный.

Answer (score 1):

Стоит попробовать использовать относительные единицы измерения em или rem.
em – задаёт размер относительно шрифта родителя.
rem – задаёт размер относительно шрифта всего документа html.
[Статья с примерами em и rem](https://habrahabr.ru/post/280125/)